# CSS3 Jumping Position

Tags: html, animation, css

So I have implemented a CSS3 transition to scroll a wide image across the screen using this code

```
    animation-name:scrolling;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

    @keyframes scrolling
    {    
        0%   { background-position: 0% 0%; }
        100% { background-position: -2000px 0%; }
    }
```

Works fine, but after 20 seconds it jumps back to the beginning, does any one have any idea how I can continually scroll it without jumping back to beginning after 20s. If I adjusted duration this would just slow down scrolling and then jump after the duration.

Also do you know how I can pause the animation on with the hover event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add another keyframe in the middle with the full position (Assuming you want the bg to go back to where it came from, if not just set it to -4000px)

```
 @keyframes scrolling
    {    
        0%   { background-position: 0% 0%; }
        50% { background-position: -2000px 0%; }
        100% { background-position: 0% 0%; }
    }
```

Should do the trick :)

Comment: This is good, but I wanted the image to repete infinatly scrolling off to the left. Your code will simply bounce from left to right won't it? Thanks for help though

Comment: Yes, but if you change the last keyframe to -4000px, it'll reset to the first postion then scroll again (I hope).